# Cannot make FileInput, it throws errors during rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, admin-on-rest

Hi what I want to do is to make FileInput inside my Create action of Admin On Rest panel.

Below is my Create action definition.

```
import React from 'react';
import {Create, SimpleForm, TextInput, ReferenceInput, SelectInput, FileInput, FileField} from 'admin-on-rest';

export default (props) => (
  <Create {...props}>
    <SimpleForm>
      <TextInput source="name" />
      <ReferenceInput label="Project" source="projectId" reference="projects" allowEmpty>
        <SelectInput optionText="name"/>
      </ReferenceInput>
    </SimpleForm>
    <FileInput source="files" label="Related files" accept="application/pdf">
      <FileField source="src" title="title" />
    </FileInput>
  </Create>
);
```

And it throws errors such as https://pastebin.com/E6zae4k6

Do you have any ideas why?

Comment: Have you tried moving `<FileInput />` inside `<SimpleForm />`?

Comment: That was the point, thank you very much I appreciate that, also I feel so dumb right now that I didn't noticed it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Create, SimpleForm, TextInput, ReferenceInput, SelectInput, FileInput, FileField} from 'admin-on-rest';

export default (props) => (
  <Create {...props}>
    <SimpleForm>
      <TextInput source="name" />
      <ReferenceInput label="Project" source="projectId" reference="projects" allowEmpty>
        <SelectInput optionText="name"/>
      </ReferenceInput>
      <FileInput source="files" label="Related files" accept="application/pdf">
        <FileField source="src" title="title" />
      </FileInput>
    </SimpleForm>
  </Create>
);
```

Comment: put some effort into that answer, simple code paste is not enough.

Comment: @Lukasz'Severiaan'Grela - There is a slight change in the code which will resolve this error. <FileInput /> component is moved inside <SimpleForm  />

Comment: Not the point. You should explain why you propose this solution. Explain why OP encountered problem etc.